# Equivalent of UIApplication.shared.preferredContentSizeCategory in app extension

Tags: ios, ios-extensions, uitraitcollection

My [open source library](https://github.com/Raizlabs/BonMot) needs to be able to call `UIApplication.shared.preferredContentSizeCategory`. But `UIApplication.shared` is unavailable in extensions. The build error suggests that I find a view controller-based way to solve my problem, but I'm writing a library, so I don't have access to any view controllers. Is there a way to get the root view controller of an extension, or a way to get the outermost `UITraitEnvironment`?

I support iOS 9+, but this feature could be 10+ if that makes it possible.

Comment: Is the view controller not providing the correct value? What about `self.view.window.preferredContentSizeCategory`?

Comment: I'm not in a view or a window. This is an instance function that I'm adding to `UITraitCollection`, and I want to find the current trait environment's current trait collection. You can see the reasoning [here](https://github.com/Raizlabs/BonMot/issues/251). I could just compile that part out, but I'd rather actually support dynamic type in extensions.

Comment: I could just mention that `sharedApplication` actually exists in extensions, just artificially blocked due to how Apple have set up their extensions lifecycle. `UIApplication.value(forKey: "sharedApplication") as! UIApplication` will give you what you want. ;-)

Comment: What does `UIScreen.main.preferredContentSizeCategory` return? I think `UIScreen.main` is available in extensions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `UIScreen.main.traitCollection.preferredContentSizeCategory`.
The `preferredContentSizeCategory` property is available on iOS 10 or later.

Comment: NB you can't use this property in `viewDidLoad` but it is available in `viewWillAppear`